# JS / insert created dom tag

Tags: javascript, dom, makefile, element

I'm trying to insert a div element created by js into the dom, can't seem to get it working...something i'm missing?

html

```
<div id="someID"></div>
```

js

```
    function addElementals(element, parent)
{
    someId.insertBefore(element.parent);
    }
    let newElemental = document.createElement('div');
    newElemental.setAttribute('id', 'user_name');
    newElemental.innerHTML = "i'm from jupiter";

    let referencePoint = document.getElementById('someId');
    addElementals(newElemental, referencePoint);
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `someId != someID` - also, I would not count on the fact that ID's are exposed as properties of `window` because if you have some code that declares `someID = 'a chicken';` then your assumption will fail ... always use `.getElementById` or `.querySelector`

Comment: also `element.parent` ... only refers to the passed in `element` and elements do NOT have a property called `parent`

Comment: having inspected the code, I think you want `parent.parentElement.insertBefore(element, parent);` perhaps

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your AddElementals function and someId to following:

```
function addElementals(element, parent)
{
//to add at end of parent
parent.appendChild(element);
//to add at beginning of parent
//parent.insertBefore(element,parent.childNodes[0]);
}

let newElemental = document.createElement('div');
newElemental.setAttribute('id', 'user_name');
newElemental.innerHTML = "i'm from jupiter";

//and someID must be exactly same as your html ID. As @Jaromanda X mentioned someID!=someId
let referencePoint = document.getElementById('someID');
addElementals(newElemental, referencePoint);
```